# Send SMS to a Recepient

Tags: android

I am writing an app in which i am trying to *send SMS to a Recepient*, but whenever i do click on Send, getting message:- **SMS faild, please try again later!**

Please see below screen shot, like you can see, here *i am trying to send message to Rahul*...

Manifest.xml:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

Please check code below:

```
       private TextView name;
private ListView list;
private Database db;
private Contact contact;
Button buttonSend;
EditText textSMS;

private Map<String, AuthenticatorDescription> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, AuthenticatorDescription>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.editor);

    // bind GUI components
    this.name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editor_name);
    this.list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.editor_list);

    // check if contact id is valid
    this.db = new Database(getContentResolver());
    int contactId = getIntent().getIntExtra(CONTACT_ID, NO_CONTACT_ID);
    this.contact = this.db.getContact(contactId);
    if (this.contact == null) {
        finish();
    }
    this.name.setText(this.contact.getName());

    // pre-load information about all account types
    AuthenticatorDescription[] authTypes = AccountManager.get(this).getAuthenticatorTypes();
    for (AuthenticatorDescription authDesc : authTypes) {
        this.map.put(authDesc.type, authDesc);
    }

    // bind list events
    this.list.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    this.list.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);

    // create the GUI
    updateView();



    saveGreeting = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.greeting);
    saveGreeting.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            customGreeting(v);
        }
    });
    buttonSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSend);
    textSMS = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSMS);
    buttonSend.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

          String recepient = name.getText().toString();
          String sms = textSMS.getText().toString();

          try {
            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(recepient, null, sms, null, null);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Sent!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "SMS faild, please try again later!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
          }

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: so what is in your stack trace?

Comment: @John3136 i am not able to send message to Rahul, and getting message: SMS faild, please try again later! ...

Comment: that is your error message that you wrote. Not the stack trace.

Comment: Wont work with Emulator.You need to test in actual device

Comment: @John3136 yes i have given in catch, to know message sent or not, and it showing me "Message Failed", it means i did mistake in my code, please check my code and tell me is it the right code to send message to Recepient(here Rahul): String recepient = name.getText().toString();

Comment: I think you have your answer (use a real device not an emulator), but you still need to learn about debugging techniques - like looking at your stack trace when you get an exception.

Comment: @SanketPandya few days ago i wrote an app, in which i was able to send message without any problem, so while i check in emulator i got message sent not Message Failed, it means doing something wrong in code..